# Fill down a row on VBA

Tags: vba

I am trying to find out how to fill down (or copy?) a row (`lastUsedRow`) up to the last row. However I find myself struggling with designating ranges (especially because I am working on different datasets that have different sizes).

**Before**

I need to spot the `lastUsedRow` (`lastUsedRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row`) - which is row 31 here. It designates the latest row where there was data in column A.

Then I want to tell VBA to fill down until the last row (`lastRow`) - row 39 - which can be found using `lastRow = .Range("E" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row`. It designates the latest row where there was data in column E.

[image]

**After**

[image]

**Question**

VBA recommends to work with `Range().FillDown` but I struggle with designating the range when coding for changing datasets. More precisely, how to I write down a range that is between `lastUsedRow` and `lastRow`?

Comment: It would seem that your `fillRange` is not correct, then. If you need to fill it to A39, then why do you define it only to A20?

Comment: `Set fillRange = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:A" & lastRow)`?

Comment: @DavidZemens from what he said and shows, maybe more like `Set fillRange = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & lastUsedRow & ":D" & lastRow)` ?

Comment: @DavidZemens, the excerpt is not related to the visual example. My problem is that I want to automate the process for columns A to D when the range is not known (but where I can infer `lastUsedRow` and `lastRow`)

Comment: Please update your excerpt so that it shows your *actual* attempt and where you are *actually* stuck.

Comment: I'm sure it's a pretty straightforward answer but yet I can't figure it out - I have edited my initial post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want to fill down Columns A thru D, from the `lastUsedRow` (defined from Col A) to the `lastRow` (defined from Col M), using the values from `lastUsedRow` in columns A:D.

```
Dim lastRow as Long, lastUsedRow as Long
Dim srcRange as Range, fillRange as Range
With Worksheets("Sheet1")
    lastUsedRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    lastRow = .Range("M" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    ' Fill values from A:D all the way down to lastUsedRow

    Set srcRange = .Range("A" & lastUsedRow & ":D" & lastUsedRow)
    Set fillRange = .Range("A" & lastRow & ":D" & lastUsedRow)

    fillRange.Value = srcRange.Value
End With
```

If you need to preserve formatting, then use the `Copy` method:

```
    srcRange.Copy Destination:=fillRange
```

Note: +1 to you for using See [correct way to find the 'last row'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11169445/error-in-finding-last-used-cell-in-vba)

Comment: Thanks for taking some time to help me out! However instead of filling down, it erases lastUsedRow (that I am meant to fill down up to the last row)

Answer (score 0):

```
lastUsedRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    lastRow = .Range("M" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
```

I think above 2 lines will give same result.