# Macro/VBA: Datasets have different sizes, how can I ensure the macro only runs on cells with data in them?

Tags: vba, excel

I created a macro in a worksheet with 1200 rows. This number will change weekly. This week, I have 970 rows. When I ran the macro, which has some IF functions built in, it gave me "FALSE" for the ~230 rows difference (when I recorded the Macro, I did a "fill down" on the columns.

This is not a duplicate because I cannot find any article that tells me **where** to put the code in VBA.

How can I ensure it only works with data-filled cells?

I checked these resources:

[Fill down a row on VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38595407/fill-down-a-row-on-vba)

[Error in finding last used cell in VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11169445/error-in-finding-last-used-cell-in-vba/11169920#11169920)

I think `lastUsedRow` might be my best option, but I don't know where to put it in VBA or if it even is my best option.

Here's the snippet where it autofills:

```
Range("J2").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
    "=IF(RC[2]=""Marketing CG2"",""Call Group 2"",IF(RC[2]=""Marketing CG3"",""Call Group 3"",IF(RC[2]=""Marketing CG1"",""Call Group 1"",IF(RC[2]=""Marketing"",""EDIT SKILL""))))"
Range("I2").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
"=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(""Nurture"",RC[-1])),""New Producer Nurture""," & _
"IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(""WB FU"",RC[-1])),""Event Follow Up""," & _
"IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(""WS FU"",RC[-1])),""Event Follow Up""," & _
"IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(""WS REM"",RC[-1])),""Event Promotion""," & _
"IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(""Marketing OB"",RC[-1])),""General Marketing""," & _
"IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(""Marketing Direct to Agent"",RC[-1])),""Marketing""," & _
"IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(""Info Email Response"",RC[-1])),""Lead Outreach""," & _
"IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(""Marketing IB"",RC[-1])),""General Marketing""," & _
"IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(""ZProgramsMatch"",RC[-1])),""Lead Outreach""," & _
"IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(""Registration Support"",RC[-1])),""General Marketing""," & _
"IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(""Complete Market Lead"",RC[-1])),""Lead Outreach""," & _
"IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(""Canada"",RC[-1])),""General Marketing""," & _
"IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(""Web Contact Form Outreach"",RC[-1])),""Lead Outreach""," & _
"IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(""General Product Inquiry"",RC[-1])),""General Marketing""))))))))))))))"
Range("I2").Select
Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("I2:I1070")
Range("I2:I1070").Select
Range("J2").Select
Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("J2:J1070")
Range("J2:J1070").Select
Columns("I:I").EntireColumn.AutoFit
Columns("J:J").EntireColumn.AutoFit
Columns("J:J").EntireColumn.AutoFit
```

Comment: is this the actual VBA code in your worksheet?

Comment: Yes, partially. I can include the entire code, if that would help.

Comment: is there any column that is always filled?

Comment: Yes, any column between A and AI will be filled with data in a changing number of rows. Columns I, J, W are those with autofill (they are created and filled during the macro running)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Last non-empty cell in a column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5441885/last-non-empty-cell-in-a-column)

Comment: So lastRowUsed is actually the best option. you can store it in a variable and use the variable to set the ranges. And you should definitely recode: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba  ;  https://www.businessprogrammer.com/power-excel-vba-secret-avoid-using-select/  ;  http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/4-mistakes-can-avoid-programming-excel-macros-vba/

Answer (score 1):

put `dim lrow as integer` at start of code
use this after if formula ends

```
lrow = Range("I" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

Range("I2").Select
Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("I2:I" & lrow)
lrow = Range("J" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Range("J2").Select
Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("J2:J" & lrow)
```

Comment: I tried this, but it returned an error 1004: Autofill Method of Range class failed at this line: `Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("I2:I" & lrow)`

Comment: `Sub CRF()
'
' CRF Macro
'

'
    Dim lrow As Integer
    
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 2
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 3
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 4
    Selection.AutoFilter` is how I placed it at the beginning of the code.